# Angular directive doesn't resolve promise

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to Angular. I've written an application that uses ngResource to get data in the controller from a rest service and display it as a table in the view.

```
codeSetup.controller("ResourceController",
    function($scope, MyModel){

    ...

        $scope.loadAll = function(){
            $scope.myModel = MyModel.query();
        }
        $scope.loadAll();

});
```

I need to give the user the option to download the data as a CSV file. I've done this by writing a directive that uses the template to create a link with a download attribute and encoding the data as text/csv as the href value. The data is bound in the DDO scope of the directive. This worked with mock data, but when the real rest service is called, the data is being passed to the directive as $$state. I get that this is a promise being passed to the directive but I don't know how to resolve this promise. How can I do it?

I'm not tied to any particular version of Angular that I have to use.

Thanks

Comment: maybe `MyModel.query().then(function(res) { $scope.myModel = res.data; })` within your `loadAll` function? It seems like that is where you're assigning the promise to your `myModel` rather than using `.then` to handle the resolved promise. Might be worth reading into how promises work.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried, but it still doesn't resolve in the directive. I need to do some more reading and also understand the lifecycle better.